# Error al obtener el valor de un RadioButton en Localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Tengo el siguiente problema; al obtener los valores de una tabla y pasarlo a sus respectivos cajas de textos, péro en el radiobutton que es de estados solo me marca el ultimo casillero es decir si en la tabla selecciono el campo hombre  solo se marcaria ese input ,  desearia obtener el valor del radiobutton y mostrarlo en el respectivo radio

**Codigo en java scripts**

```
const Editar = (codigo) => {
  let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));

let codigos = document.getElementById("codigo");
let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
let apellido = document.getElementById("apellido");
let direccion = document.getElementById("direccion");
let correo = document.getElementById("correo");
 let cboCiudad = comboCiudad.options[comboCiudad.selectedIndex];
 let cboProfesion =comboProfesion.options[comboProfesion.selectedIndex];
 let cboEstado = comboEstado.options[comboEstado.selectedIndex];

 let rbtnHombre = document.getElementById("rbtnHombre");
 let rbtnMujer = document.getElementById("rbtnMujer");

let Edit = arrayLista.find(e => e.codigo == codigo);
let Select = arrayLista.findIndex(e => e.codigo === codigo);

      codigos.value=Select;
      codigos.value= Edit.codigo
      nombre.value= Edit.nombre
      apellido.value= Edit.apellido
      direccion.value= Edit.direccion
      correo.value= Edit.correo
      cboCiudad.text=Edit.cboCiudad
      cboProfesion.text=Edit.cboProfesion
      cboEstado.text=Edit.cboEstado

       let rbtnOpcion = "";

      if (rbtnHombre.checked) {
        rbtnOpcion = "Hombre";
    } else  {
         rbtnOpcion = "Mujer";
    }
       rbtnHombre.checked=Edit.rbtnOpcion
       rbtnMujer.checked=Edit.rbtnOpcion
```

}

**codigo en html**

```
 <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-1 pt-0">Genero: </legend>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="rbtnHombre" 
                value="Reset" value="Hombre" >
                <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    Hombre
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="rbtnMujer" value="Reset" value="Mujer" >
                <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    Mujer
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mirá, esto pasa porque los radiobuttons solo puede estar seleccionado uno de todos los que estén en una lista, para poder solucionar esto vas a tener que crear un form por cada item de la lista.

```
<div class="row">
<form>
<!--[otro código html, si hay más campos] -->

        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-1 pt-0">Genero: </legend>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="rbtnHombre" 
                value="Reset" value="Hombre" >
                <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    Hombre
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="rbtnMujer" value="Reset" value="Mujer" >
                <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    Mujer
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ya lo hice pero no me funciona solo quiero al seleccionar un registro los radiobutton se marquen respectivamente